# Powershell Start-Process -Credential

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell

I seem to have some issue with running elevated administration using powershell.

To be honest, im not that good with powershell.

So im running this script [powershell -command "Start-Process iexplore -Verb -RunAs"].

I understand that powershell Start-Process cmdlet has the parameter -Credential.

But when i do Get-Help Start-Process , it doesnt explain this parameter and google didnt bring me anywhere close.

Running -RunAs at the end calls my local admin instead of my AD admin ID , this is fine.

I would like to know how to actually insert my User ID/Password in the powershell Start-Process line.

Running RunAs within Command Prompt isnt going well, but i  do know it is easier there with "/User:[user] password".

Comment: you can't use `-credential` and `-verb` in the same `start-process` command. I'd use `-credential (get-credential)` or use encrypted password to automate this: https://www.adminarsenal.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/. Keep in mind, `-verb RunAs` Creates an admin token to get rid of an UAC dialog, but will run as the current user. `-credential` will run as the specified user, but won't surpress the UAC dialog.

Comment: @SimonS - oh hei there.. thx! i was trying to figure out how to do it. so then how do i launch iexplore in Admin without using -Verb RunAs?

Answer (score 2):

The -credential parameter is used like this:

```
-credential "ComputerNameOrIP\admin"
```

Examples:

```
-credential "192.168.1.1\admin\"

-credential "SomeComputerName\SomeUsername"
```

In the case of domain accounts, just use the domain name instead of computer name and it works just the same.

If you use this correctly, when started, it will spawn a logon screen where you just have to type the password and click OK.

You can store the password in an external file and then use it in the script.

```
 read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\pass.txt

$password = get-content C:\pass.txt | convertto-securestring

$credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "UserName",$password
```

Comment: Currently after running my current script , the logon screen does pop up , and it is using my local admin.

I do prefer using my local admin access as the application running requires local admin instead of my Domain admin.

Would like to know how to save the password in the line , or maybe we have something like /SaveCred in cmd.

Comment: Added a way to use password to the answer.

Comment: so i use the script above , save it as pass.txt? Asking the real question. heh. as i've seen this script via google , but thats the problem, i have no idea how the -credential works. now with this , i would like to ask , i save it as pass.txt as example. then in my script how do i add the -Credential? is it [powershell -Command "Start-Process iexplore -Credential pass.txt -Verb -RunAs"] ?

Comment: Saving passwords in cleartext *anywhere* is one of the ***worst*** possible security practices anyone could possibly conceive of (*if not **the** worst*).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - Can suggest me another solution?

Comment: but of course , i can always put the path to my Synology NAS on an admin only folder.

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin - You may want to look at [this TechNet Gallery item for using the Windows Credential Manager](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Credentials-d44c3cde)

Comment: Hi @JeffZeitlin I get this error. [link](http://imgur.com/a/BJXkx) upon doing a demo test on my pc. I have done Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned via powershell ISE x86 on Admin. Still the same error.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - this command worked for me. now im able to do the CredMan.ps1. [Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted]

Comment: then in my original script , is it now like this? [powershell -Command "Start-Process iexplore -Credential $CredMan.ps1 -Verb RunAs"]

Comment: The text file is to store the password so you can use it in the script. And  Jeff Zeitlin, what you say is absurd. It's a local text file and it's parsed in a secure manner.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin : Are you serious? Putting a password in clear text in a text file is "OK" in your mind? Do you work in the industry? Zetlin is correct. And there are better solutions. You can put the password as an encrypted string into a .txt file and decrypt it, it's not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The -Credential parameter can also be used with a `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential` object, and this is much more secure.  Within Powershell, you can create an object of this type with

```
$UserName = 'domainpart\userIdPart'
$SecureStringPassword = Get_Password $UserName
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName,$SecureStringPassword)
Start-Process $SomeExe -Credential $Credential ...
```

Then you must implement a `function Get_Password` to retrieve the password in some secure manner.  Reading a clear-text password from a text file is NOT the way to go.  As Zeitlin says above, it is perhaps the worst security practice one could conceive of - even worse that putting your password on a sticky on your screen.

Instead, store the password as an encrypted string in the .txt file as follows.  First, get a password as input, encrypt it, and store the encrypted string:

```
function Global:Get_PasswordFileName($Username)
{
    $baseName = "encrypted_$UserName.txt" -replace '\','_'
    "${env:LOCALAPPDATA}\$baseName"
}

$encryptedString = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter password for $UserName" | convertfrom-securestring
$passwordFileName = Get_PasswordFileName $Username
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($passwdFileName, $encryptedString)
```

There are many ways to write the file, `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines` is just one, and `Get_PasswordfileName` can be tweaked to use any reasonable directory.

Then define `Get_Password` as

```
function Global:Get_Password($UserName)
{
    $passwordFileName = Get_PasswordFileName $Username
    $EncryptedString = Get-Content $passwordFileName
    ConvertTo-SecureString $EncryptedString
}
```